# JavaScript - having same ID for multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript

If I assign the same id to multiple dom elements e.g.

```
txtBox.id="1"
txtBox2.id="1"
```

Are there any issues with this? Performance, compatibility etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** there can be performance issues.

Use **class** if you are going to assign the same name to multiple elements.

Comment: what are the performance issues...im clear as to y we should not use this ...but it would be great if you can tell me what performance issues might be there?

Comment: I used 1000 similar **id**'s for my somewhat popular website and it took 3 seconds to load in Chrome, changing them to **class** removed all 3 seconds of parsing time. My guess is that browsers simply expect **id**'s to be unique and aren't in any way optimized for the case when they are not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. **DO NOT DO THIS**

IDs are meant to be unique.
Use a class if you want a few the same.

Also IDs should **not** start with a numeric value

Comment: can you elaborate...because when i do this there are no errors on the page?

Comment: abbas of course there are errors. when you try to select by ID only **one** of them would be selected

Comment: @abbas: Wrong.  [There are errors on the page](http://validator.w3.org/).  You just didn't check.

Comment: Just for the record, IDs starting with numbers are fine in HTML5.

Comment: @FelixKling I just said they shouldn't, I never said it was wrong ^_^

Comment: I also question why it won't work. In fact, I am looking for a definitive answer. What if you have three tables in one html page, and each table has a separate id ("week_1", "week_2", "week_3"), but the trs and tds within each table have same ids ("row_1" and "monday", etc.)? Can't we access each id as the child of the unique table id?

Comment: Technically yes you can but it is bad practice @GregoryLewis

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

- `id` attributes [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) within an HTML document,
- `id` attributes starting with a number are [only](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) supported in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea. Dom id values should be unique.

**Added** Things will probably break in weird, browser-specific ways. (And there is already enough weird, browser-specific stuff, you don't want to add the opportunity for any more!)

**Solutions**

1. If you want the values settable from the markup too, then consider the DOM `class` of the element. Remember that an element can belong to multiple classes.
2. If the values will only be used by Javascript, then use any non-reserved property name that you like. Eg `category,` `group,` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is suppose to represent a single unique element, if you need multiple elements to be identified through a single entity use `class`.

The performance impact will come in the form of when you run into unexpected problems with Javascript not working properly, CSS not applying properly, and so forth...

The problem using the same id will come when you use javascript like `document.getElementById()`  the keyword there is `element` **singular**, it will only return 1 element, where's if they were classes you'd use `document.getElementsByClassName()` and return multiple `elements` **plural** with that class name.

Comment: It might return only one element. It might return a nodelist. Welcome to Inconsistent Browser Error Recovery Hell.

Comment: I once moved some SQL from MySQL to Postgresql, that involved a lot of rewriting. I've heard some nightmares about C having to be seriously hacked about to get it to move between platforms. I don't think there is any language in which people can't screw up locale stuff without having to even leave the OS.

Comment: I just mean no other language is like web programming where you have to worry about your code running on 20 different platforms all with there own quirks, rules, regulations, and guidelines.  You have 5-6 major browsers, some running on multiple OS's (MAC, Linux, Windows), some on mobile devices (iPhone/Android/Windows Mobile), and the sad part is even the same browser can act totally different on any one of those platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other opinions that it isn't a good idea. However, you can effectively reference elements in an html page that have the same ids. I made a calendar-type table whose table id="week", and then there were lots of rows with their own ids, and then the TDs had their own ids like "m","t","w","th","s","su" and so forth and so on.

Then the client said he wanted to be able to look at the previous week calendar, and the next week calendar. So I wrote three identical tables on one page, and using a JQuery slider, you could slide the weeks back and forth. Then my JavaScript calculations stopped working, and I realized it was because each table had identical TR and TD ids.

So I started giving new unique ids for each TR and TD, appending the week id to the normal id, something like id="m_week0" or id="m_week-1" etc.

That seemed to be over complicated, because there were just too many elements with ids-per-table, so I rolled back that idea.

Instead, I referenced each id by associating it with its parent table, which had its own unique id: `$("table[id='week0'] #m").html()`.

Now I can loop over each week, and get/set the values or inner html of each element, even if they have the same ids as TDs and TRs that occur in other tables:

```
var value = 1;
for(var week=-1;week<2;week++){
    $("table[id='week"+week+"'] #m").html() = value; // monday
    value++; //simple increment as an example

    $("table[id='week"+week+"'] #t").html() = value; //tuesday
    value++; //simple increment as an example

    $("table[id='week"+week+"'] #w").html() = value; //wednesday
    value++; //simple increment as an example

    $("table[id='week"+week+"'] #th").html() = value; //thursday
    value++; //simple increment as an example

    $("table[id='week"+week+"'] #f").html() = value;  //friday
    value++; //simple increment as an example

}
```